# What is usage and purpose of Bitrate in AWS Elastic Transcoder Presets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, transcoding, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I want to transcode a video using aws elastic transcoder jobs. I have checked video transcoding with [preset](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/home?region=us-east-1#preset-details:1351620000001-400050) id "1351620000001-400050" for "Smooth 800k" and this preset having max bitrate 688

Is this mean 688 kbps?? 
And the input video transcoded with in OR equal to 688??

Refer the image,
[image]

If it is, in my case it behaves differently,

An input video bitrate of "10479 kbps", it was transcoded into 5812 kbps.

Is it expected behaviour??

What is the purpose and usage of Bitrate in AWS ealstic transcoder presets?

Kindly provide your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Bit Rate is the video bit rate of output file in kilobits/second. If you select a video with a lower bit rate than the selected bit rate, your video bit rate will be lower. Valid values for bit rate depend on the codec that you chose.

You can encode videos in different bit rates to support different types of devices and different types of connection e.g. bandwidth available.

Amazon has a good page describing all of this.

[Elastic Transcoder Preset](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/preset-settings.html)